# Possible to view an MPMoviePlayerController within a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, video, collections, mpmovieplayercontroller, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build a UICollectionView in which each cell holds an MPMoviePlayerController with a different video. I want the user to be able to play each video in place.

I know that you can't play multiple instances of an MPMoviePlayerController. What's vague about Apple's documentation is whether or not you can instantiate and place them in views - the way I read it, you actually CAN do that. However, I couldn't get that to work so I finally gave up and tried a different technique.

Instead, I tried using a select event to instantiate, place, and automatically play the video within the collection cell. As a control, I placed an additional view outside of the collection view, within the same UIViewController. When I ran it, the outside view loaded up just fine - the video instantiated and the first frame appeared. And all the cells in the collection view appeared correctly, as well. However, when I selected one of the collection cells, the video in the outside view disappeared entirely while the video in the collection view instantiated but failed to appear. I know it instantiated because I color-coded the background of each of the views and on selecting the cell, the background for the video appeared, but the actual video did not. Very confusing.

So I'm wondering if you can even put a video within a collection view at all?

Here's the code for the view controller:

```
#import "testViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "tvCollectionCell.h"

@interface testViewController ()

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (strong) MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer;

@end

@implementation testViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                                             [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                              pathForResource:@"testvideo" ofType:@"mp4"]]];

    CGRect videoFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height);

    [[self.videoPlayer view] setFrame:videoFrame];

    self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = FALSE;
    self.videoPlayer.repeatMode = TRUE;
    [self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.videoPlayer view].backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    [self.containerView addSubview:[self.videoPlayer view]];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    tvCollectionCell *tvCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"tvCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tvCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

    return tvCell;

}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    tvCollectionCell *tvCell = (tvCollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                      initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                                                           [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                            pathForResource:@"testvideo" ofType:@"mp4"]]];

    CGRect videoFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tvCell.frame.size.width, tvCell.frame.size.height);

    [[movie view] setFrame:videoFrame];

    movie.shouldAutoplay = TRUE;
    movie.repeatMode = TRUE;
    [movie prepareToPlay];
    [movie view].backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [tvCell addSubview:[movie view]];

}

@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any update on this? Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that there is a reference to all the videos?
It could be that the only property for the MPMoviePlayerController aka videoPlayer
is being over written, you could try allocating an array to hold a reference to each video that you have and then retrieve that reference and play that video controller.

Comment: self.videoPlayer is the control video that instantiates separately from the video in the individual cells. In `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you'll see where a new MPMoviePlayerController is being instantiated each time a cell is selected.